# Apache 2.4.7 setenvif to build an LDAP group name for require directive

Tags: ldap, apache2.4

Can I use an expression in a `require` directive in Apache 2.4.7 to require a specific LDAP group based on a regular expression that matches a portion of `Request_URI`?

To give a little background, I'm trying to use Apache 2.4.7 and `http-git-backend-wrapper` to limit access to specific Git projects using LDAP -- [see my existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281115/restrict-access-to-git-repository-based-on-ldap-groups). The question here is more specific than that one, so I don't *think* this is a duplicate; answering this question is sufficient to answer that question, but answering that question isn't sufficient to answer this one, and I can't find an answer to this specific question anyway.

Here's my configuration.

```
CustomLog "/path/to/git.log" "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b Git Project:%{GIT_PROJECT}e // %{LDAP_GROUP}e"

<LocationMatch "^/git/[^/]+">
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/git/([^/]+)" GIT_PROJECT=$1
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/git/([^/]+)" LDAP_GROUP=cn=$1,ou=projects,dc=mydomain,dc=com
    Order deny,allow
    AuthName "Authentication Required"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPUrl ldap://ldapserver/ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=com?uid
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off

    # This one doesn't work --- %{GIT_PROJECT} shows up in my LDAP logs
    #Require ldap-group cn=%{GIT_PROJECT},ou=projects,dc=mydomain,dc=com

    # This similarly doesn't work --- %{LDAP_GROUP} shows up in my LDAP logs. 
    Require ldap-group "%{LDAP_GROUP}"

    # As a sanity check, I copied the LDAP group generated by a specific
    # request from the Apache log, and this works.
    #Require ldap-group cn=copied-from-log-apache-log,ou=projects,dc=mydomain,dc=com
</LocationMatch>
```

***edit:*** Short answer: you can't without upgrading Apache.

Comment: Can you clarify which newer version of Apache supports this? Thanks!

Comment: Replying to myself: I guess the answer might be 2.4.8, per the change log:

  *) mod_authz_user, mod_authz_host, mod_authz_groupfile, mod_authz_dbm,
     mod_authz_dbd, mod_authnz_ldap: Support the expression parser within the
     require directives. [Graham Leggett]

Comment: Hey, @ThomasQuinot. Sorry for taking a while to reply. Unfortunately, I didn't take a note about where I got my "short answer" from, and it's been a while since then. Regardless, thank you for adding info to the question.